# Showing and hiding List items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following menu:

```
<li style="display:none" class=".logged_in">Menu 1</li>
<li style="display:none" class=".logged_in">Menu 2</li>
<li style="display:show" class=".logged_out">Menu 3</li>
```

I use Ajax to call an endpoint to test whether a user is logged in or not. If logged in, I want to hide menu 1 and 2, and show menu 3, if not, then the opposite is true.

I have been trying to hide and show the items like such:

```
$.find('.logged_out').css("display", "show");
$.find('.logged_in').css("display", "none");
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I also tried a number of variations such as:

```
$(".logged_out").show();
$(".logged_in").show();
```

Any idea of the correct way to do this?

Comment: Well there is no "show" value for display...Check out the the properties for display in the mozilla developer network and try that.

Comment: Do your classes actual begin with dots, or is that a goof?

Comment: :) yes, that was the mistake. tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of those will hide your element (except you should use a valid value for the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property because `show` isn't one).

Your problem is that you have dots in the class names themselves. Consequently, your jquery selector is looking for elements with classes `logged_in` and `logged_out` and can't find them because your classes are called `.logged_in` and `.logged_out`.

Change:

```
<li style="display:none" class=".logged_in">Menu 1</li>
<li style="display:none" class=".logged_in">Menu 2</li>
<li style="display:show" class=".logged_out">Menu 3</li>
```

To (remove dots in the class names):

```
<li style="display:none" class="logged_in">Menu 1</li>
<li style="display:none" class="logged_in">Menu 2</li>
<li style="display:show" class="logged_out">Menu 3</li>
```

If you want to use the dot, then check out [@BG101's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678826/3928341)

Comment: Thanks totally missed that!

Answer (score 2):

**@nem's** answer is correct. but if you **HAVE** to have a dot in the class name, you can escape the dot like so:-

```js
$('.\\.logged_in').show()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class=".logged_in" style="display:none">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if the element has `class=".logged_in"`, you can still target the element to show/hide using the following `With` selector expression :

```
$('[class=".logged_in"]').hide();
$('[class=".logged_out"]').show();
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will target all elements that **contain** these classes in their class names. For example, it will also hide elements with class `user_logged_in` since it contains the class `logged_in`.

Comment: this approach you don't need the `with`, it will work like this `$('[class=".logged_in"]')`.

Comment: @nem,Bg101 - Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't think it that way.

Comment: you forgot the trailing single quotes on the both selectors :)